# Anaconda cannot import ssl but Python can

Tags: python, openssl, anaconda

Anaconda 3 Jupyter notebook cannot import ssl but using Atom terminal to import ssl has no problem.

I am trying to import ssl in Jupyter notebook but is given the following error:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py in <module>
     96 from enum import Enum as _Enum, IntEnum as _IntEnum, IntFlag as _IntFlag
     97 
---> 98 import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
     99 
    100 from _ssl import OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER, OPENSSL_VERSION_INFO, OPENSSL_VERSION

   ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

But if I run python in Atom terminal (which presumably invokes Python instead of Anaconda) and import ssl.  There is no problem at all.  I can even check up the OpenSSL version which is

```
>>> python
>>> import ssl
>>> ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION
>>> 'OpenSSL 1.1.0i  14 Aug 2018'
```

I have tried to add the Anaconda3 installation directory 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3' to system path but it does not work.  I have tried to uninstall and reinstall Anaconda3 but it does not work either.

Both the version of python in Anaconda3 and the standalone Python are 3.7.1 and the operating system is Windows 8.1.  And Anaconda3 system info is as follows:

```
(base) C:\Windows\system32>conda info -s
sys.version: 3.7.1 (default, Dec 10 2018, 22:54:23) [...
sys.prefix: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
sys.executable: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe
conda location: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda
conda-build: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-build.exe
conda-convert: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-convert.exe
conda-debug: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-debug.exe
conda-develop: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-develop.exe
conda-env: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-env.exe
conda-index: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-index.exe
conda-inspect: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-inspect.exe
conda-metapackage: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-metapackage.exe
conda-render: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-render.exe
conda-server: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-server.exe
conda-skeleton: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-skeleton.exe
conda-verify: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-verify.exe
user site dirs:

CIO_TEST: <not set>
CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV: base
CONDA_EXE: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe
CONDA_PREFIX: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER: (base)
CONDA_PYTHON_EXE: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe
CONDA_ROOT: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
CONDA_SHLVL: 1
HOMEPATH: \Users\J
PATH: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:
\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\P
rogramData\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\bin;
PSMODULEPATH: C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
PYTHONIOENCODING: 936
REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE: <not set>
SSL_CERT_FILE: <not set>
```

Comment: Probably related to [this](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/3343). Can you check with [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) what locations in both cases are used to look for the SSL library?

Comment: @Kit Strangely now Atom terminal import does not work either...