# Anaconda can use SSL but sublime text that is setup with anaconda cant use SSL

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, python-requests, sublimetext3

My problem is the opposite of this problem here: [Anaconda cannot import ssl but Python can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55792063/anaconda-cannot-import-ssl-but-python-can)

when I start IDLE with anaconda prompt this line of code works

```
requests.get(url)
```

but when I do this in the sublime text it shows this error. what am I missing here?

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='bikroy.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bn/ads/sylhet-division?page=1 (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))
```

Comment: Is anaconda in the PATH variable in Windows?

Comment: Yes.anaconda is in the PATH

Comment: What build system are you using? Sublime Text > Tools > Build System

Comment: I'm using the conda build system